# how to fix this (fundation templates &inheritance)

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

refrence:[`enter image description here`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tz5g5.png)/
   
[C++ Error] homeworkUnit1.cpp(39): E2102 Cannot use template 'bag' without specifying 
   specialization parameters
   
integral code: 
   https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wBe7IqHngArjK3WVSN3u-mboKhrMkIao/view?usp=sharing
   
(using Borland C++ Builder)

> .h

```
template <class T>

class bag{
  public:
      bag(int);//
      ~bag();
      String result();
      T *data;
      bool empty,full; 
  protected:
     int size,position;
     String ans;  
};
template <class T>
class stack:public bag<T>{
  public:
    stack(int);
    void push(int);
    void pop();
};
template <class T>
class queue:public bag<T>{
  public:
    queue(int);
    void enq(int);
    void deq();
};
```

> .cpp

```
stack<float> *s;
queue<float> *q;
template<class T>bag<T>::bag(int num){
  empty,full=false;
  size=num;
  data=new T [size];
  position=0;
}
template<class T>bag<T>::~bag(){
  delete []data;
}
template<class T>String bag<T>::result(){
  String ans="";
    for(int i=0;i<=position-1;i++){
      ans+= AnsiString(data[i]);
    }
  return ans;
}

**template<class T>stack<T>::stack(int num):bag( num){//how to fix this
}**
```

what i need to add or my code is wrong

Comment: Try use `bag<T>` instead.

Comment: .@ songyuanyao  Could you please tell me more detail ,where i need to change bad<t> sorry about that,i am beginner

Comment: `template<class T>stack<T>::stack(int num):bag<T>( num){`

Comment: thx i fixed it!! :]

Answer (score 0):

Since you inherit `bag<T>`, you have to specify `bag<T>` as the inherited type you want to explicitly construct:

```
template<class T> stack<T>::stack(int num) : bag<T>(num) {
//                Specify the template argument ^^^
```

This is necessary because C++ allows multiple inheritance, and you could inherit different instantiations of the same template:

```
template <typename> class foo {};

class bar : public foo<int>, public foo<float> {
public:
    bar();
};

bar::bar() : foo{} {}
//           ^^^
// Same problem, but now it's clear why: which foo instantiation?
// foo<int> or foo<float>?
```

And, perhaps just as important, when you explicitly call a base type constructor, the grammar says you have to specify a type, and `bag` *isn't actually a type* -- it's a *type template.*

Comment: oh, I see.Thank you so much. : >